# Set term factors dynamically from an imported cplex-Model

Tags: java, optimization, cplex

Let's say i have an OptimizationModel `abc.lp`, which i want to import with the CPlex java-API. I use: `importModel` function ([click](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.ide.help/refcppopl/html/classes/IloCplex.html)) to import it. Now i want to change some decision variable's factors in the constraint or in the objective. For example the imported model `abc.lp` looks as follows:

`Objective: Minimize <factor1>x1 + <factor2>x2`

```
Constraint: <factor1>x1 + <factor2>x2 <= 40
```

For me `factor1` and `factor2` are input parameters of a function. So i get:

```
public void(double factor1, double factor2){
...
cplexModel.import("path/to/abc.lp")
// Change parameters, how to do it?
```

Is there a handy way to set the factors dynamically from an imported Model with the Cplex-API?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Is there something remaining that you think needs to be addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  It's not very intuitive, at least to me.

Here's an example snippet that assumes a LP (linear objective and constraints):

```
 // Read model from file with name args[0] into cplex optimizer object
 cplex.importModel(args[0]);

 // Get the objective and modify it.
 IloObjective obj = cplex.getObjective();
 IloLinearNumExpr objExpr = (IloLinearNumExpr) obj.getExpr();
 IloLinearNumExprIterator iter = objExpr.linearIterator();
 // Loop through the linear objective and modify, as necessary.
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
   IloNumVar var = iter.nextNumVar();
   System.out.println("Old coefficient for " + var + ": " + iter.getValue());
   // Modify as needed.
   if ( var.getName().equals("x1") ) {
      iter.setValue(42);
      System.out.println("New coefficient for " + var + ": " + iter.getValue());
   }
 }
 // Save the changes.
 obj.setExpr(objExpr);

 // Assumes that there is an LP Matrix.  The fact that we used
 // importModel() above guarantees that there will be at least
 // one.
 IloLPMatrix lp = (IloLPMatrix) cplex.LPMatrixIterator().next();
 for (int i = 0; i < lp.getNrows(); i++) {
    IloRange range = lp.getRange(i);
    System.out.println("Constraint " + range.getName());
    IloLinearNumExpr conExpr = (IloLinearNumExpr) range.getExpr();
    IloLinearNumExprIterator conIter = conExpr.linearIterator();
    // Loop through the linear constraints and modify, as necessary.
    while (conIter.hasNext()) {
       IloNumVar var = conIter.nextNumVar();
       System.out.println("Coefficient for " + var + ": " + conIter.getValue());
       // Modify as needed (as above).
       if ( var.getName().equals("x1") ) {
          conIter.setValue(42);
          System.out.println("New coefficient for " + var + ": " + conIter.getValue());
       }
  }
  // Save changes (as above).
  range.setExpr(conExpr);
}
cplex.exportModel("modified.lp");

// Solve the model and display the solution if one was found
if ( cplex.solve() ) {
   // do something here.
}
```

Here, we're looking for a variable named "x1".  We set it's coefficient to 42 in the objective and in all linear constraints.  The `println`'s are for debugging.  I did this quickly, so make sure you test it.  Otherwise, you should be able to modify that to suit your needs.  Hope that helps.